# django save websocket to redis without closing it

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis

Is there a way to keep websocket open using redis for future use ?

I need my django server to communicate with a websocket backend service on behalf of the client.

It means that I need to save the websocket open between multiple http requests of the client.
can I use redis for this purpose or is there any other way to do so ?

Thanks.

Comment: can I somehow use coroutines for that purpose? instead of redis, that is.